# Error while clipping gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I was following this [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#processing_gradients_before_applying_them) for gradient clipping while working with a multilayer perceptron.

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy_loss, trainable_variable)
capped_grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_global_norm(gv[0],5), gv[1]) for gv in grads_and_vars]
optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_grads_and_vars)
```

tensorflow shows the following error,

```
in clip_by_global_norm raise TypeError("t_list should be a sequence")
```

**trainable_variable** is a list which I created while creating the model. assume I have a trainable variable(tf.Variable), I add this variable to  ***trainable_variable*** list by the following command.

```
trainable_variable.append(var) #where ver is a trainable variable in tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point of this type of problem is, **trainable_variable** list may contain multiple tensors who are not initialized or used in the graph. make sure you contain all the tensor safely in the **trainable_variable** list. Sometimes even they might contain **NaN** for gradient computation. This type of error may also introduce for unnatural value.